# Unable to install vagrant plugin due to SSL_Connect error

Tags: ruby, vagrant-windows

Hello so I am trying to install a vagrant plugin but I getting the following error in mingW64

```
$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-winnfsd
Installing the 'vagrant-winnfsd' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Vagrant failed to load a configured plugin source. This can be caused
by a variety of issues including: transient connectivity issues, proxy
filtering rejecting access to a configured plugin source, or a configured
plugin source not responding correctly. Please review the error message
below to help resolve the issue:

 SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Source: https://rubygems.org/
```

I am behind a firewall and have to pass the company cert manually. I updated my Ruby certs but still no luck. Anyone have any clue why vagrant is not taking my pem/certs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well funny thing. Vagrant uses its own certs. Inside of its folder:

the path is: C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\cacert.cert on windows.

Add your company cert and you should be good to go.

I solved my own issue. Hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: How to add my conmpany cert ?

Comment: Can you explain how exactly did you resolve this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure how to add company cert. but It should be in that same location. As far as how I solved it. It was 3 years ago, but I remember exposing the config and searching my entire computer for files that end in `cert` then changing stuff to expose a value that wouldn't break anything. Then I found the file that linked to the vagrant instance. In my case I have 3 installations and 8? certs (JAVA, JS, C#, Python) each had 1 or 3. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

vagrant plugin install --plugin-clean-sources --plugin-source https://rubygems.org vagrant-hostmanager

it works for me ...